# LocalAiChatModel results into java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout

Tags: java, chatbot

While trying to run https://github.com/langchain4j/langchain4j-examples/blob/main/devoxx/src/main/java/_12_ChatWithDocumentsExamples.java, for for "localai" instead of "openai", by replacing chatLanguageModel in ConversationalRetrievalChain with LocalAiChatModel.

With below configuration I keep on getting - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout - all the time even after changing timout to 3 minutes:

```
                chatLanguageModel = LocalAiChatModel.builder()
                    .modelName("ggml-model-gpt4all-falcon-q4_0.bin")
                    .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
                    .temperature(0.0)
                    .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                    .maxRetries(3)
                    .logRequests(true)
                    .logResponses(true)
                    .build();
```

I also tried other models like - llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin, orca-mini-3b.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin

Comment: Mostly this was due to insufficient CPU, as when I checked the utilization it was 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the timout to a higher value (e.g. 10 minutes)

```
ChatLanguageModel model = LocalAiChatModel.builder()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
                .modelName("lunademo")
                .temperature(0.0)
                .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
                .logRequests(true)
                .logResponses(true)
                .build();
```

Using only CPU just takes sometimes a long time to answer. Using GPU will be 20 times faster.